# Ice wizard attacking defending clan castle troops

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm preparing for war (TH 9) and I've found great success with GoWiPe (2x Golem, 3 Pekka, 6 skeletons and rest wizards). So I figured I'd try replacing wizards with ice wizards (as they cost so much less). However, when I was doing some challenges it didn't appear the ice wizards were shooting at the defending dragon. However according to their information, they do attack air units to.

Is there anything that's different about the ice wizards preferred target, compared to the wizards? Is there anything special about them shooting flying troops? Are regular wizards better in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Source: http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Ice_Wizard

> - Ice Wizards prioritize defensive structures above all other targets,
>   and will bypass all other types of enemy buildings and troops while
>   any defenses remain on the battlefield. This is true even if they are
>   under attack by enemy Clan Castle troops, heroes or Skeleton Trap
>   skeletons. Note that like all troops that prioritize defenses, Ice
>   Wizards do not consider the Clan Castle to be a defense regardless of
>   whether or not it contains enemy troops, but do consider the defending
>   Grand Warden to be a defensive building.
> - Once all defenses are
>   destroyed, Ice Wizards become like any other troop with no preferred
>   target; they will attack the nearest building to them regardless of
>   type, and will turn and attack enemy units if they become aware of any
>   nearby.

So you can try taking a couple of wizards and a couple of ice-wizards in your attack instead of taking all ice-wizards!

*Happy Clashing!*